# How to overlap textView and editText in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, material-design, textview

Hi I'm currently working of a user details layout and trying to achieve something, Can someone point me on how to extend the edittext to overlap on textview and make it look like of just a single row? also how can I align it? Appreciate for any help.

screenshot:

[image]

xml:

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:id="@+id/textView_data"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textName"
                    android:layout_margin="0dp"
                    android:text="Full Name:"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Full Name"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                    android:id="@+id/textView_data2"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:gravity="fill_vertical" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

expected output that i want is like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this by using a framelayout.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="40dp" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Full Name : " />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple layout

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="User Info" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="Full Name:"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textView_data2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:hint="Full Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you can not overlap views.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:id="@+id/textView_data"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" //This line might help
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textName"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:text="Full Name:"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Full Name"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:id="@+id/textView_data2"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"//Remove this line
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"//Remove this line
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:gravity="fill_vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Sir, thanks for the response i update my question so that you can see the image of what I would like to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

First place an edittext and make it not editable then on press make it editable.
this may solve your problem

Or

use android hint it will get the desired output